# Index.html not Loading anything from Three.js

Tags: html, typescript, three.js

I've been building a website using three.js with typescript. Only my header from my index.html shows when I try and load it onto a local server.

I am trying to load in a model.glb using three.js from an external main.ts file.

My console does not recognize the file and says that it cannot be found.

---

---

GET http://localhost:8081/src/client/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

---

:8081/#:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8081/src/client/main.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

---

localhost/:33     GET http://localhost:8081/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I have tried to rewrite both of the html and the main.ts file; and I converted the main.ts file to a main.js as so the terminal could read it. I am fairly confident that paths are all correct, but I could definitely be wrong. the HTML and MAIN.JS are below ⬇️

```
<body>
    <header>
        <script>
            async function fetchAndAppend(url, target) {
                const response = await fetch(url);
                const content = await response.text();
                document.querySelector(target).innerHTML = content;
            }

            fetchAndAppend('./menu.html', 'header')
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('An error occurred:', error);
                });
        </script>
    </header>

    <main>
        <script src="src/client/main.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    </main>
</body>
```

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var THREE = require("three");
var GLTFLoader_1 = require("three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader");
// Create a scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 5;
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
var loader = new GLTFLoader_1.GLTFLoader();
loader.load('/dist/client/public/WebPSRV4.glb', function (gltf) {
    var model = gltf.scene;
    scene.add(model);
    var animate = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
    animate();
}, function (xhr) {
    console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded');
}, function (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
});
```

Comment: A 404 is a self descriptive error, it's telling you exactly what's happening. Web servers generally don't let you read any file from the local file system, you have to explicitly make files public. It depends on what server you're using. Your `node_modules` folder is not publicly available on your server. Search for how to serve static files with whatever server you're using. This issue isn't related to Three.js

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot load local files using HTML. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.155.0/three.min.js should be the correct link to include. Also if I'm correct you need to load your code after you load three.js or else it may not find it. You also cannot use `require` like in regular node.js. Three.js should already be loaded and you don't need to do anything else. You need to know that browsers know nothing about your local filesystem and you need to put your files in a place your server can serve.